# Spring Autowired object have all null field when meet @Cachable

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private String name;
    //fields omitted
    //@Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#name")  //once added, the name will be null.
    public User getUser(String name) {
    }
}

@Service
class UserServiceBuilder(){
    public UserService build(ConfigBean config){
        UserService s = new UserServcie()
        s.name = config.xxxx
        //other config omitted
        return s;
    }
}

@Configuration
class AppConfig{

    @Bean
    public UserService UserService(UserServiceBuilder builder, ConfigBean configBean) {
        return builder.load(configBean);
    }

}

class UserCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private UserService UserService; // get null when the @Cachable 

}
```

`UserService` is created by the `UserServiceBuilder` which will read a log of properties from the config file.

Then the `UserService` will be injected to `UserCtrl`, it works at first.

However once I add the `@Cachable` to one method of `UserService`, all the fileds of the injected `UserService` will be null.

It seems like that spring will create a proxy of `UserService` when using cache, and the proxy object does not have the fileds.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right it's because of the proxy. You must add getters in the UserService and use this getters if you want take the fields of the UserService outside.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private String name;
    //fields omitted
    //@Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#name")  //once added, the name will be null.
    public User getUser(String name) {
    }

    //ADD THIS:
    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }
}
```

But if you add output inside UserService method:

```
public User getUser(String name) {
  System.out.println("PING " + this.name);
  ...
}
```

you will see that this.name inside object is not null.

P.S. and I think that you can remove `@Service` annotation from `UserService`. Because you have `@Service` and `@Bean` registration of `UserService`. It's confusing.

Comment: Add a getter does not slove the problem.

Comment: @hguser I wrote test-project to check: [my github](https://github.com/asmln/sb-test-proxy-service-bean). Note the comments in UserService and the application.properties.

Comment: I have checked that, and you are right. But you have to use `getName` in the instance method otherwise the `name` is still null.